# Ms BotBuilder : firstRun dialog prevents triggering of other dialogs based on LUIS intents

Tags: botframework

I have a `firstRun` dialog defined in the bot like this :

```
// First run dialog
    bot.dialog('firstRun', [
        function (session, next) {
            session.userData.token = _.get(session, 'message.user.token', null) ||  _.get(session, 'userData.token', null) 

        }
    ]).triggerAction({
        onFindAction: function (context, callback) {           
            var score = 0;
            if (session.userData.token doesn't exist or new token recieved in `session.user.message.token`){
                score = 1.1;
            }
            callback(null, score); 
        }
    });
```

And there's a LUIS model integrated with a dialog that triggers on an intent, let's say `Help` :

```
bot.dialog('help', [
        (session, args) => {

            let entities = _.get(args, 'intent.entities', null);

            let topic = _.get(builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(entities, 'topic'), 'entity', null) || _.get(args, 'option', null);


            session.replaceDialog(topic);
        }
    ])
    .triggerAction({
        matches: 'Help'
    });
```

The `onFindAction` triggers on every message. And it triggers `firstRun` only on the first message when `session.userData.token` is not set.

Problem is, if the first message is matched to `Help` intent, it does not get triggered. It works from the second time, when `firstRun` is not triggered.

How can I ensure any matching intent triggers the corresponding dialog, irrespective of `firstRun`?

If there's a different way possible to achieve the same thing, please suggest.

**Addition**
What I am trying to accomplish is this - I have a web service auth token that I want to keep in session.userData.token that refreshes every hour. So right now I trigger `onFindAction` on every utterance which checks if either `session.userData.token` doesn't exist (which means its the first utterance) OR a new token has been sent. In both cases I trigger `firstRun` to update `session.userData.token` and proceed to trigger any dialog that matched with the LUIS intent of the utterance. But whenever `firstRun` is triggered, none of the other dialogs are triggered. It would be ideal to have a simpler mechanism to do this i suppose.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? Always run `firstRun` in response to first user's utterance and then start processing the intents?

Comment: @PavelVeller : Yes, please check Addition.

Comment: @PavelVeller : Also I suppose middlewares could be used. How would you suggest I utilize a middleware for firstRun like functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to have a *pass-through* intent handler that would trigger before the message is routed to the *actual* handlers. [Middleware](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#use) would be the best place to handle your `token` refresh logic, but working with `session` in your middleware isn't easy. This blog post of mine explains why - http://www.pveller.com/smarter-conversations-part-4-transcript/.

Your best bet is the `routing` event, I believe. It's synchronous via [`events`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_eventname_args) and you are given the `session` object. You should be able to validate and refresh your `token` as needed before the message reaches the proper intent handler destination.

```
bot.on('routing', function (session) {
    if (!session.userData.token) {
        // receive new token 
    }
});
```

Unlike middleware though, you are not given the `next` callback to continue the chain, so you will have to make sure you fetch the token synchronously. The blog post I mentioned previously explains this part as well.